# What is meant by onclick = "javascript: javascript: function(value);"?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I know this - `onclick = "javascript: function(value);"`. 
what is the purpose of writing javascript twice as in

```
onclick = "javascript: javascript: function(value);" ?
```

please help.

Comment: I have this in my code and unable to decipher why javascript is written twice.

Comment: there is no point, that is just garbage... don't use it at all, period.

Comment: If you have it in your code, *we* should ask *you* why it is there, no? :P

Comment: @Amadan, no :P if code not only OP

Answer (score 1):

There is no good reason to include the "javascript" protocol. It is most likely an error.

I would also mention that you should consider attaching click events using DOM APIs. For example:

```
document.getElementById('el').addEventListener('click', function(value) {...});
```

Comment: there's no good reason to use a do-nothing label once, much less twice... it's not a protocol, like it would be if used on an href...

Comment: @dandavis technically it is a protocol: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767736(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: no, it's not. that's only in a url context, like your link demonstrates. used in an event attrib context as shown by OP (where a pure js program body goes), it's a label, which is an unused javascript feature. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: we're saying the same thing. very unlikely that it was meant to be a label. it was intended to be used as a protocol because the developer confused href with onclick.

Comment: even if it doesn't break anything, not knowing if/when/where to use it screams out "noob alert" to anyone reading your code, so avoid it like the plauge... the resemblance to a protocol segment of a url is coincidental, but good coders know the difference ;)

Comment: In fact, OP's code yields an error in my Chrome: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Label 'javascript' has already been declared".